# InnoSetup (Pascal): FileExists() doesn't find every file

Tags: inno-setup

It seems, that some files which I wanna check with FileExists() can never be found even if they are there, others are found every time.

If I put the file "driver.sys" into the "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\" directory, it would never be found (FileExists is false every time i call the function).
If I move the file into the Windows root "C:\Windows\" it is found.

This doesn't work (while the file is definitely in the folder 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\'):

```
function isNotDriverInstalled(): Boolean;
begin
  if (FileExists('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\driver.sys')) then begin
    Log('File exists');
    Result := False;
  end else begin
    Log('File doesn''t exist');
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

This works (while the file is in the folder 'C:\Windows\'):

```
function isNotDriverInstalled(): Boolean;
begin
  if (FileExists('C:\Windows\driver.sys')) then begin
    Log('File exists');
    Result := False;
  end else begin
    Log('File doesn''t exist');
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Btw: I am using Windows 7, 64 Bit.

Has anybody experienced such a case before?
Any suggestions?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `System32` directory is mapped to the `SysNative` path due to [`File System Redirector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so as you can see, hardcoding of such directory path is not that easy. Better use one of built-in constants listed below:

***1. The {sys} constant:***

You can use the [`{sys}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#sys) constant, but make sure you allowed the setup to run in 64-bit mode. For more information about how to do it, see the [`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode.htm) directive reference and be sure to read the [`64-bit Installation Limitations`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_64bitlimitations.htm) topic.

From the [`{sys}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#sys) constant reference:

> The system's System32 directory. For example: If you used
>   {sys}\CTL3D32.DLL on an entry and the system's Windows System
>   directory is "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM", Setup or Uninstall will translate it
>   to "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\CTL3D32.DLL".
>
> On 64-bit Windows, by default, the System32 path returned by this
>   constant maps to the directory containing 32-bit system files, just
>   like on 32-bit Windows. (This can be overridden by enabling 64-bit
>   mode.)

Here is how you can use it:

```
if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{sys}\drivers\driver.sys')) then
  Log('File exists');
```

***2. The {syswow64} constant:***

From the [`{syswow64}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#syswow64) constant reference:

> On 64-bit Windows, the system's SysWOW64 directory, typically
>   "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64". This is the actual directory in which 32-bit
>   system files reside. On 32-bit Windows, 32-bit system files reside in
>   "System32" or "System", not in a separate SysWOW64 directory, so this
>   constant will resolve to the same directory as {sys} if used there.
>
> Do not use this constant unless you have a specific need to obtain the
>   name of the actual directory in which 32-bit system files reside.
>   Gratuitously using {syswow64} in places where {sys} will suffice may
>   cause problems. (See the documentation for the [Files] section's
>   sharedfile flag for one example.)

Here is how you can use it:

```
if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{syswow64}\drivers\driver.sys')) then
  Log('File exists');
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, but sadly for me this doesn't work either. I tried these variants already before I posted and just posted the full path without constants because I thought at least this should work. Now I know, the other variant should work better, but really it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried to print out e.g. by using `Log()` method, what file path you're passing to the `FileExists` function ?

Comment: Yes, {sys} gives me this path:
[19:06:17,992]   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\driver.sys
..thats right except system32 is written uppercase at my file system.

Comment: I see, the `{sys}` constant maps to the directory containing 32-bit system files. You would have to allow running setup in 64-bit mode by modifying the value of the [`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode.htm) directive. That should fix this problem, but be sure to read the [`64-bit Installation Limitations`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_64bitlimitations.htm) topic.

Comment: Glad it helped! I should have mentioned this before (but I didn't realized it). I've added a short note about 64-bit into the post update.

Comment: FileExists(fileName) does not work (returns false) but LoadFromFile(fileName) works (value of fileName is the same) ...

Comment: @hfrmobile, what is `LoadFromFile` (method of which class) ? Note, that such method (of whatever class it is) does not consider redirection.