# Make Inno Setup use system32 and/or syswow64 as directed blindly

Tags: inno-setup

I need some help with Inno Setup please.

My problem is getting it to place "files" and perform "actions" where I want them "BLINDLY".

To make a long story short, with but one exception, it seems that every thing I want done to/in the "System32" folder is ending up in/on the "SysWow64" folder. It does not seem to matter how I call it, {sys}, {syswow64}, {sd}\windows\system32, {sd}\windows\syswow64, or in my code section, %systemdrive%\windows\system32, %systemdrive%\windows\syswow64, or Expandconstant('{sys}')\filename.exe, and so on. I even tried hard coding "c:\windows\system32\filename.exe" and so on. In every case except one, it did it on/in the syswow64 folder.

I know the difference between the system32 and the syswow64 folder. (64bit vs 32bit) I have spent over a week trying to get my code to put things where I tell it to "blindly". Lots of research in the many forums, including here, none seem to give good information and clear examples that show me how to have the control I need. I know which file is 32 bit, which is 64 bit and which folder each should go in to. But Inno Setup, incorrectly thinks it knows better.

I wish I could turn off that feature and make it use the absolute paths I choose as I write them in code etc., but I have not found a way to do that so I am asking how to make Inno Setup put things where I tell it to go, not where it thinks it should go.

No matter how I have tried, the best I can do is get it to back up the files I am going to overwrite in the system32 and in the syswow64 folder correctly. After that "everything" is always done on the syswow64 folder, again, no matter how I code the path or what flags I use such as 64bit, etc.

My goal with this program is two fold, the main one is to learn how to use Inno Setup to take control of a file/folder, changing permissions as needed, copying over the target file, then restoring the perms etc. I can do this all day long with .bat files. But I want to use Inno Setup because it can help me do the Uninstall" part of my project which will undo the changes I want to make and restore the files back to their original configuration etc. (That part of this project will probably require my coming back to this forum for additional help)

What this specific code is going to do is replace the Windows 10 calculator with the Windows 7 version, which I prefer. And I want to use Inno Setup so that I can have an "Uninstaller" put it all back. I know others have already written code to do this, and I have access to those programs from trusted sources that I am sure are not putting out "Evil" posing as "Good", but in my enterprise environment, I cannot take a chance and the only 100000% way I can be sure such code is evil free is to write it myself. Plus, as I said, it provides an excellent opportunity to learn several techniques at once.

As I said I can, and have written a .bat file which can back up the existing calc.exe files, which in the 64 bit version of Win 10 exist in both the system32 and syswow64 folders, which is why I need my code to do things to "both" folders, and replace them with the corresponding Win 7 versions and so on so I know it is possible to do this. I just need to know how to do it in Inno Setup. My code, several different versions due to playing with paths syntax, have all been able to backup and overwrite the calc.exe file in syswow64, but not system32 on a 64bit Win 10 OS.

My code is posted below. In it you can see many commented lines which show the different ways I have tried to put in the paths as I need them. You will also see that I am trying not to need to embed a .bat file with my calls to ICACLS.exe and Takeown.exe for permissions control and I am using, maybe incorrectly, the "Beforinstall" option to have the permissions backed up and then changed on the target file so that I can overwrite it etc. I am also trying to avoid doing anything in the "run" section as that should not be needed in this project. I also have a lot of message boxes to give me feed back which will be commented out on the final version as well as the "/k" will be changed to "/c" or, if I can get it to work, just call the ICACLS.exe and Takeown.exe programs directly instead of shelling out to "cmd.exe" first. I have had that work, but switched to the cmd.exe method with the /k for better feed back during this trouble shooting phase etc. This code is expected to be run 99.99% of the time on a Win 10 x64 OS, but must be able to handle correctly being run on a Win 10 x86 OS as well. (I am on Win 10 x64 V1709 for this project)

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)

AppId={{C771AFC7-CC36-4749-962D-119AD2671213}
AppName=Clasic Calculator
AppVerName=Classic Calculator Win 7 Style
AppPublisher=ACollege
AppPublisherURL=www.Acollege.edu
AppSupportURL=www.Acollege.edu
AppUpdatesURL=www.Acollege.edu
CreateAppDir=no
OutputDir=C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Setup
OutputBaseFilename=SetupClasicCalc
ArchitecturesAllowed= x86 x64
;ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=
PrivilegesRequired=admin
MinVersion = 0,5.0
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
CreateUninstallRegKey=yes
UpdateUninstallLogAppName=yes
uninstallable=yes
SetupIconFile="C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\calc-1.ico"





[Languages]
;Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:ASpyFolder.isl"

[Dirs]
;Win 10 Section


[Files]
;Windows 10 Section

;Testline for how is it running


;Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\*.*"; DestDir: "c:\TempTest"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags:  createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: WhatIsIt


Source: "{syswow64}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and not IsWin64

Source: "{sys}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64


;Source: "{sd}\windows\system32\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sd}\windows\system32\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and not IsWin64

;Source: "{sd}\windows\system32\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sd}\windows\system32\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit external; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "{syswow64}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\*.*"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\System32\*.*"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\*.*"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and not IsWin64


;Source: "{win}\system32\en-US\calc.exe.mui"; DestDir: "{win}\system32\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "calc.exe.mui"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10



[Registry]

[INI]

[Run]

[Code]

Function WhatIsIt(): Boolean;

begin

    if Is64BitInstallMode then

    begin  

      MsgBox('Installing in 64-bit mode', mbInformation, MB_OK)

    end

    else

    begin

      MsgBox('Installing in 32-bit mode', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    end;

    if IsWin64 then

    begin

      MsgBox('This is 64bit system', mbInformation, MB_OK)

      MsgBox('(PF64)-bit program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{pf64}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

      MsgBox('(PF32)-bit program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{pf32}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

      MsgBox('(PF) program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{pf}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

      MsgBox('(SYS) program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{sys}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

      MsgBox('(SYS64) program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{syswow64}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

      MsgBox('(SYS32) program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{syswow64}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    end

    else

    begin

      MsgBox('This is NOT 64bit system', mbInformation, MB_OK)

      MsgBox('32-bit program files reside in: ' + ExpandConstant('{pf32}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);

     end;

    Exit


end;



Procedure ChangeCalcPerms();

var 
  CommandLine: String;
  ResultCode: Integer;

begin

  CommandLine := '"' + ExpandConstant('{sys}') + '\calc.exe"' + ' /save ' + '"' + ExpandConstant('{sys}') + '\calc.perms"'

  (*CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /save ' + '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.perms"'*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Backup Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  shellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Backup Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '/F "' + ExpandConstant('{sys}') + '\calc.exe"' + ' /A'

  (*CommandLine := '/F "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /A'*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Make Owner Admin Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('Takeown.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Make Owner Admin Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '"' + ExpandConstant('{sys}') + '\calc.exe"' + ' /grant Administrators:f'

  (*CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /grant Administrators:f'*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Give Admin Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('System 32 Give Admin Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /save ' + '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.perms"'

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Backup Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Backup Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '/F "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /A'

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Make Owner Admin Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('Takeown.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Make Owner Admin Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /grant Administrators:f'

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give Admin Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give Admin Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /grant System:f'

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give System Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give System Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  (*SECDeleteSYSWOW*)

  CommandLine := 'Del "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"'

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Del Calc.exe Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ShellExec('','CMD.exe', '/k ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  (*Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  (*Exec('ICACLS.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)*)

  MsgBox('Syswow 64 Del Calc.exe Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);


end;



function IsX64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Is64BitInstallMode and (ProcessorArchitecture = paX64);

  (*MsgBox('IsWindows64 Result is: ' + inttostr(Integer(Result)), mbInformation, MB_OK)*)

end;


function IsIA64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Is64BitInstallMode and (ProcessorArchitecture = paIA64);
end;

function IsOtherArch: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not IsX64 and not IsIA64;
end;


function IsWindowsXP: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major = 5) and (Version.Minor = 1);
end;


function IsWindowsVista: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major= 6) and (Version.Minor = 0);

end;

function IsWindows7: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major = 6) and (Version.Minor = 1);

end;

function IsWindows10: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin

  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major= 10) and (Version.Minor = 0);

  (*MsgBox('IsWindows10 Result is: ' + inttostr(Integer(Result)), mbInformation, MB_OK)*)

end;

function IsWindowsVista_or_7: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major = 6) and ((Version.Minor = 1) or (Version.Minor = 0));

end;

function IsWindowsVista_or_7_or_8: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major = 6) and ((Version.Minor = 2) or (Version.Minor = 1) or (Version.Minor = 0));

end;


function IsWindows8: Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
  S: String;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);

  Result := Version.NTPlatform and (Version.Major = 6) and (Version.Minor = 2);

end;
```

Somehow, within the first 3 lines of the "Files" section I am able to get the program to correctly create a sub folder called "W10CalcBak" and copy the correct "calc.exe" file in to it in both the system32 and the syswow64 folders. But after that, everything seems to happen to the syswow64 folder only. I have tried running the "Beforeinstall" part in the 1st three "backup the targets" lines of code, and where it is now in the part of the "Files" section where I actually replace the calc.exe files. All with the same result.

When I run the code as currently written it will execute the backup the files part correctly using the following 3 lines of code.

```
Source: "{syswow64}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and not IsWin64


Source: "{sys}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "{syswow64}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64
```

In the below picture you can see the two backup folders etc..... Opps
Stupid think wont let me put up pictures... WAAA, and says it will put in a link instead. Not very smart of it. I don't know why it would think that is going to work as the picture is on a local HD on a local PC behind many firewalls and is not on a webpage etc or even a system with "IIs" setup or installed etc.....

Then it goes to the first line in the "Proceedure" called "ChangeCalcPerms" via the "BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms" option in the following code line.

```
Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\*.*"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64
```

At that point I have many msgbox lines to help me see what it is doing etc.

When the first message box is shown it has the "resolved" path info in it which as you can see in the picture below is set to the correct system32 not syswow64 folder. After I click OK, a DOS window opens, the "ICACLS.exe" command is given, the next picture will show that it seems the correct path to system32 was used in the DOS window and then after I exit that DOS window the third picture of the results message box returns the correct success code of "0". But the "calc.perms" is not in the "system32" folder even though in everything I can see it shows system32. It is instead in the "syswow64" folder. That is what I need to stop/control. I need that line to do its work on the system32 folder not the syswow64 one.

OK no pictures, see comments above. But believe me it is showing "system32" in all the right places, but it is doing all the work in "syswow64".

The source files from the Win 7 system that I am writing the code on and compiling it on are stashed in two folders, the system32 and the syswow64 along with the en-US sub folder with the proper calc.exe.mui language file etc. I know which one is the 64bit version, the one from the system32 folder, and which one is the 32 bit version. But in the end the only file copied is the 32 bit version in to the syswow64 folder, the 64 bit version is not copied, probably because the permissions do not allow it as they are not getting set as they should due to the problem I am having getting it to use and act on the system32 folder when I want it to etc.

I would show more pictures that would show how it seems to resolve the paths correctly but yet seems to only do things in the syswow64 folder but I can't so I am just going to ask if anyone out there would please take a look at the code and see if they can find what I am doing wrong and explain how I can correct it.

Thank you VERY VERY much in advance to all who try to help me,

Ralph

Comment: Please post the install log for your installer.   For your screenshots, you can upload the files to an image host like imgur.com if you can't host them yourself.

Comment: You can not overwrite a protected system file. Open a cmd window with admin rights. you are now in the system32 folder. Type `ren calc.exe calc.off` you will get an error. Or `move calc.exe C:\calc.exe`

Comment: I admit, I didn't read whole your question (it's way too long for this site). But I got an impression that you know how to deal with System32/SysWow64 issue in regular sections, like `[Files]` (using `64bit` flag). But you have problems with `[Code]` section. There you need to use `EnableFsRedirection` function: [Inno Setup: Checking existence of a file in 32-bit System32 (Sysnative) folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49501554/850848).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mirtheil, Moskito, and Martin for your help,

To Mirtheil,

Thank you for the suggestion on how to post my images. Since Martin's suggestion lead to an answer I don't think I will need to post the screen shots, but thanks again for the idea.

To Moskito,

While it is not recommended, you can indeed overwrite a system file. You just have to take ownership and grant yourself full control over the file. My project does exactly that by making calls to system programs such as ICACLS.exe and TakeOwn.exe found in the Windows OS. This can be done in a .bat file to. You must have admin rights but it can be done. Thanks again for trying to help.

To Martin Prikryl

THANK YOU! Your suggestion on using the EnableFsRedirection function and the links you posted about it and how to use it lead me to a solution.

The solution required 3 changes to my code.

1. I had to use the function to disable the file redirection prior to running any commands against the "system32" file/folder.
2. I had to change my code of the "path" from using the built in Inno Setup constants {sys} and {syswow64} to using the Windows/DOS environment variable %systemdrive% to get the base drive letter and then use "\windows\system32"  to finish the path. If I used the {sys} constant it still redirected my call to system32 to syswow64.
3. I had to go back to using the "Exec" function instead of the "ShellExec" function to execute my "calls" to ICACLS.exe and Takeown.exe. If I used "ShellExec" the system still redirected my system32 calls to syswow64.

I also had to make some adjustments to my files section to finish the install part of this project, mainly in the order of the "Sourece" lines and when I called the "ChangeCalcPerms" procedure and I went from a single "Star.Star" style of copying my "new" files to the system32 and syswow64 folder and the "en-US" sub folder for the .mui files to using a separate line of code for each of the four files I needed to place in the "system" folders. This was required because the BeforeInstall/AfterInstall functions will be run for each file in a "Star.Star" type of call and that was causing my procedure to run twice which it was not designed to do and was it causing problems. (Tried to use the * symbol in "Star.Star" but it seemed to have special meaning and messed up the look of this reply)

The last thing I will need to do to complete the "Install" part of this project is to take the "new" calc.exe files, from Win 7, that I used to replace the Win 10 versions with and restore the original permissions to them for their protedction. I plan to add a new procedure that I will call using the "AfterInstall" option and I will place it in the last line of code in my files section.

Once I have added that last part and tested it, I will remove all the message boxes and the install part of the project should be done.

I will post my fixes, based on your help in the next part of the answer  so as to give a working example to those who may follow on how to do this type of coding.

I will leave in the message boxes etc in my procedure and will simply say to those who wish to use this code to remember to comment them out and change the "/k" to "/c" in the "Exec" parts of the code so that the code will run without user interaction.

My corrected Files section.....

```
[Files]

; This section backs up the calc.exe files

; This line is for x86 systems only
Source: "{sys}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and (not IsWin64)

; The next two lines are for x64 systems
Source: "{sys}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "{syswow64}\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\W10CalcBak"; DestName: "Calc.exe"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: external; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64


; This section modifies the permisions and then deletes the calc.exe files then replaces them

; Next two lines are for x86 systems only

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and (not IsWin64)

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\calc.exe.mui"; DestDir: "{sys}\en-US"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: IsWindows10 and (not IsWin64)

; Next four lines are for x64 systems only

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\System32\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; BeforeInstall: ChangeCalcPerms; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\System32\en-US\calc.exe.mui"; DestDir: "{sys}\en-US"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: 64bit createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe"; DestDir: "{syswow64}"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64

Source: "C:\InstallScripts\ClasicCalculator\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US\calc.exe.mui"; DestDir: "{syswow64}\en-US"; Permissions: authusers-full; Flags: createallsubdirs recursesubdirs overwritereadonly; Check: IsWindows10 and IsWin64
```

And here is my corrected Procedure from my Code section..

```
[Code]

Procedure ChangeCalcPerms();

var
  OldState: Boolean;
  NewState: Boolean;
  CommandLine: String;
  ResultCode: Integer;

begin

  // Test to see if x64 system, if so disable FS Redirection..

  if IsWin64 then

  begin

  Msgbox('The system is x64, turning off the FS Redirection',mbInformation, MB_OK);

  //Turn of redirection

  OldState := EnableFsRedirection(False);

  Msgbox('The system is x64, turning off the FS Redirection, OldState = ' + inttostr(Integer(OldState)) ,mbInformation, MB_OK);

  end;

  // Start of x64 and x86 as both have system32 folder

  // Backup perms for system32\calc.exe

CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /save ' + '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.perms"'

  MsgBox('System 32 Backup Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

 Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  MsgBox('System 32 Backup Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

 // Change Owner to Administrators

  CommandLine := '/F "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /A'

  MsgBox('System 32 Make Owner Admin Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

  Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  MsgBox('System 32 Make Owner Admin Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  // Grant Administrators full control

 CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /grant Administrators:f'

  MsgBox('System 32 Give Admin Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

MsgBox('System 32 Give Admin Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

 // Grant System Full Control

CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"' + ' /grant System:f'

  MsgBox('System 32 Give System Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

  MsgBox('System 32 Give System Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

 // Delete calc.exe in system32 folder

  CommandLine := 'Del "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\system32\calc.exe"'

  MsgBox('System32 Del Calc.exe Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

 Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)


  // Start of x64 part *************

if IsWin64 then

  Begin

    // Backup perms for syswow64\calc.exe

    CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /save ' + '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.perms"'

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Backup Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

 (Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Backup Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    // Change Owner to Administrators

    CommandLine := '/F "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /A'

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Make Owner Admin Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

   Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'Takeown.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

   MsgBox('Syswow 64 Make Owner Admin Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    // Grant Administrators full control

    CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /grant Administrators:f'

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give Admin Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

    Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give Admin Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    // Grant System full control

    CommandLine := '"' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"' + ' /grant System:f'

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give System Full Perms Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

 Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + 'ICACLS.exe ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Give System Full Perms Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    // Del calc.exe in Syswow64 folder

    CommandLine := 'Del "' + '%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64\calc.exe"'

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Del Calc.exe Comandline is: ' + CommandLine, mbInformation, MB_OK);

    Exec('CMD.exe', '/k ' + commandline, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)

    MsgBox('Syswow 64 Del Calc.exe Result is: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);

    end;


  if IsWin64 then

  begin

  //Turn on redirection

  Msgbox('The system is x64, turning On the FS Redirection',mbInformation, MB_OK);

  NewState := EnableFsRedirection(OldState);

  Msgbox('The system is x64, turning On the FS Redirection, NewState = ' + inttostr(Integer(NewState)) ,mbInformation, MB_OK);

  end;


end;
```

I hope this helps someone else who needs to do this kind of thing.

Next step is to get the "Uninstall" part of this working.

**THANKS!!!! again to all those who tried to help, AND DID!**

Ralph

Comment: You can use `{sd}` instead of `%systemdrive%` and `{syswow64}` instead of `%systemdrive%\windows\sysWOW64`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried using Inno Setup constants such as {sys} and {sd}, but the directive to disable FS redirection seemed to fail when I did. Only when I used the DOS env. Variable did the paths resolve correctly, once I disabled the FS redirection of course. I do not have an explanation for that but that is how it worked in my system. I needed to both disable the FS redirection and change to using DOS ENV Vars for my path and I had to use Exec instead of ShellExec as I stated in my "Fix". Thanks again for all your help. Ralph

Comment: I was not recommending to use `{sys}`. That's indeed not affected by disabling FS redirection. But there should not be any problem with `{sd}` and `{syswow64}`.